# Questions about VLAN

Tags: server

Hi I am using a desktop (Running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) and I got some problems.

How do I create VLAN on my desktop to connect it with the router?

The router itself have it's own IP address but I am required to make the router to have the VLAN's IP address. I have tried a lot of website but the IP address of the router is always the router original IP address.
Thank you very much

I have a DHCP server

Comment: Hello? Can anyone answer?

Comment: Don't you have access to the router using its Wi-Fi or cable connection?

Comment: Nope, I dont have access to the router. I setup a DHCP server and then i suppose to have a VLAN10 to connect it to the router @M.Dm.

Answer (score 0):

This [Link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/vlan) should help you. I believe you do not need to configure VLAN for your machine, if your router allows untag/access vlan configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering me! I forgot to mention I have a DHCP server. I really appreciate your help